# Arbitrary sum of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given an arbitrary (possibly infinite) index set $I$ and a set of subspaces $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $V$,  we define the sum of subspaces to be
$$
 \sum_{i \in I} W_i = \left\{\sum_{i \in I} w_i \; | \; w_i \in W_i, \; w_i = 0 \text{     for all but finitely many $i \in I$. } \right\}
$$

I want to show closure under addition, and I argued like this,

Then let $u,v \in \sum_{i \in I} W_i$, meaning that $u = u_1 + ... + u_m$ for $m \in I$, and similarly $v = v_1+...+v_n$ for some $n \in I$. WLOG, assume that $n<m$, and what we do is combine terms from each subspace as
$$
 u+v = (u_1+v_1)+ (u_2+v_2) + ... + (v_n)+...+(u_m)
 $$
Where each grouping is from one of the subspaces $W_i$ and hence $u+v \in \sum_{i \in I} W_i$.

Does this make sense? My issue is just how to deal with the arbitrary index set. If $m=n$ then it's straightforward but I don't think I can assume that right? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Addition of two finite sums is also a finite sum. Done.

Comment: Are there any kinks in my argument though? I'm really trying to focus on being rigorous for now.

Comment: You should use indices like $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n$ as you can't assume that the natural numbers $1,2,\dots$ themselves are elements of $I$. Having two such finite index sets, consider their union.

Comment: In the context of the definition of $\sum_{i \in I} W_i,$ how has the expression $\sum_{i \in I} w_i$ been defined, for every family $(w_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $w_i \in W_i$ and $w_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$? (Also, are you absolutely required to use this definition of $\sum_{i \in I} W_i$? I can think of two other definitions, neither of which requires a prior definition of the sum of a possibly infinite family of elements of $V$.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yep that's how it's defined. I suppose it's not absolute, lmk the others. Doesn't the $w_i=0$ for all but finitely many takes care of the sum of possibly infinite family of subspaces though?

Comment: @Berci thanks that makes more sense! Does that mean I can assume that the vectors are of equal length? I.e $u = u_{i_1}+ ... + u_{i_n}$ and $v = v_{i_1}+...+v_{i_n}$ or is it still the case that it could be $v = v_{i_1}+...+v_{i_m}$

Comment: The condition that $w_i \in W_i$ and $w_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i \in I$ does indeed allow the expression $\sum_{i \in I} w_i$ to be defined, but my point is that such a definition must be given before the stated definition of $\sum_{i \in I} W_i$ can make sense.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Will do.